# Chunky yeast Safeale-05 safe to pitch?

Tags: yeast, reusing-yeast

I just brewed American Red Ale, great fermentation, no off flavors.

- 11.25 lbs. Malteurop 2-row
- 0.75 lbs. Briess Caramel 60L
- 0.5 lbs. Belgian Special B

But yeast, when fermentation is finished, looks a bit strange. I wanted to add new brew on this yeast cake. Have you ever seen yeast like this, chunks not slurry?

Thank you.[image: Chunky yeast]

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine, and it is smells fine and the beer off it has no off flavours then you should be good to go.

I guess the yeast looks a bit odd because usually you would get a wide shallow yeast cake that would allow the CO2 bubbles to diffuse out, but in the longer narrower sight glass you have in the picture, the CO2 will get trapped and disturb the flocculation.

Comment: Thanx for the explanation, first time I see yeast like this specially 05.

Answer (score 1):

As long as there no off-flavours, should be safe to repitch. It's not just yeast in the cake, but also hot&cold break etc.

Answer (score 1):

That's just well flocculated yeast.

Just break it up the best you can by agitating. Even if there's still clumps the outer yeast will feed and break away and disperse as they produce cO2.

Comment: Thank you as always.Will pump the new wort from the bottom port.